# Question of google analytics hourly definition

Tags: google-analytics

I am start to use google analytics. I google a day for definition of hourly in Audience Overview but no luck.

For example in GA it show Wednesday, 3 August 2022 09:00 users:745  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O20j8.png)

I want to know it's mean at that moment 9:00, I have 745 user?
or from 8:00 to 9:00, I have total 745 user?

Answer (score 0):

It is the first; at the moment 9:00; the count of users is 745.

For the future reports on Google Analytics, you may check [Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9212670?hl=en&ref_topic=12153537,12153943,2986333,&visit_id=637970051878537188-2839437415&rd=1) from Google.